build/make/core/tasks/dex_preopt_check.mk:13: error: Build failed
I tried to merge the mainline resources for July 2024 into the AOSP code, but I found that it had a compilation error
vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys/telephony-apps/ConferenceDialer/Android.mk:17: warning: ../../../../../..//packages/apps/PhoneCommon
[ 99% 1246/1251] including vendor/qcom/proprietary/commonsys/wfd/Android.mk ...
JACK DISABLED in WFD Service =
[ 99% 1250/1251] finishing build rules ...
FAILED:
build/make/core/tasks/tools/compatibility.mk:60: warning: out/host/linux-x86/framework/catbox-tradefed.jar has no license metadata
build/make/core/tasks/tools/compatibility.mk:60: warning: out/host/linux-x86/framework/catbox-tradefed-tests.jar has no license metadata
build/make/core/tasks/tools/compatibility.mk:60: warning: out/host/linux-x86/bin/catbox-tradefed has no license metadata
build/make/core/tasks/tools/compatibility.mk:60: warning: test/catbox/tools/catbox-tradefed/README has no license metadata
build/make/core/tasks/tools/compatibility.mk:60: warning: out/host/linux-x86/framework/catbox-report-lib.jar has no license metadata
build/make/core/tasks/tools/compatibility.mk:60: warning: test/app_compat/csuite/README.md has no license metadata
build/make/core/tasks/dex_preopt_check.mk:13: warning:  Missing compilation artifacts. Dexpreopting is not working for some system server jars. See https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/tasks/README.dex_preopt_check.md
Offending entries:
system/framework/oat/arm64/apex@com.android.art@javalib@service-art.jar@classes.odex
system/framework/oat/arm64/apex@com.android.art@javalib@service-art.jar@classes.vdex
system/framework/oat/arm64/apex@com.android.wifi@javalib@service-wifi.jar@classes.odex
system/framework/oat/arm64/apex@com.android.wifi@javalib@service-wifi.jar@classes.vdex
In file included from build/make/core/main.mk:1470:
In file included from build/make/core/Makefile:7139:
build/make/core/tasks/dex_preopt_check.mk:13: error: Build failed.
10:47:46 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (52 seconds) ####```

